# How to convert OsString into utf-8 encoded string in platform-independent way?

Tags: rust, character-encoding

I need to print - and print only - OsString to user, using system that only accepts UTF-8 strings as input.

How can I convert OsString to utf8 string (one way only) the platform independent way?

I already found crate `encoding`, but I cannot find a way to detect base OsString encoding.

Comment: You can't, `OsString` itself is platform dependant.

Comment: It is in principle not possible to reliably detect encoding of a string. It is possible to try and make an educated guess but it is bound to be wrong sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading through tons of standard library documentation and source code, I've come to these conclusions.

- On Unix, `OsString` is a `Vec<u8>` and can be any arbitrary bytes, expected to be UTF-8. On Windows `OsString` is currently in [WTF-8](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/ffi/trait.OsStringExt.html#tymethod.from_wide) ([source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/sys_common/wtf8.rs.html)), which is a superset of UTF-8 that allows you to represent ill-formed UTF-16 in specifically-ill-formed UTF-8. It is sufficient to understand this as also being arbitrary bytes resembling UTF-8, as the properties of the WTF-8 encoding are only used if you recover the original bytes (see `encode_wide` below). If the same Unicode information in the OS is encoded in valid UTF-8 on Unix and valid UTF-16 on Windows, `OsString` will encode both as identical UTF-8. This is all internal and private, but helps to understand the public interface.
- The platform-specific behavior visible to users arises only in conversion.
- On reception from the OS, Windows systems use [`from_wide`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/ffi/trait.OsStringExt.html#tymethod.from_wide), which converts possibly-ill-formed UTF-16 into the encoding of `OsString` (WTF-8). Unix systems use [`from_vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/ffi/trait.OsStringExt.html#tymethod.from_vec), which just wraps the `Vec<u8>`. Both are lossless, but `from_wide` does change the layout. I believe the only way to create an `&OsStr` on Windows without first creating an `OsString` is from `str`, while on Unix you can also use [`from_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/ffi/trait.OsStrExt.html#tymethod.from_bytes) to create an `&OsStr` from a simple `&[u8]` slice.
- Windows lets you convert `OsStr` into an iterator of possibly-ill-formed UTF-16 codepoints with [`encode_wide`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/ffi/trait.OsStrExt.html#tymethod.encode_wide), which losslessly undoes the original conversion. On Unix, you can simply get the bytes back with [`as_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/ffi/trait.OsStrExt.html#tymethod.as_bytes) or [`into_vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/ffi/trait.OsStringExt.html#tymethod.into_vec). It seems like you can't get the bytes as `&[u8]` on Windows, which makes sense given the implementation.
- All Unicode-invalid `OsString` values have their validity checked when converting to `String`. However, if an `OsString` is on Windows and valid Unicode, then converting to `String` skips the validity check, as this was done when originally converting to `OsString` and stored in the `OsString` as a boolean. This boolean is only meaningful if it's true, in which case the `OsString` is ensured to be valid UTF-8. If it's false, it may or may not be valid. Unix doesn't have this boolean. That means that if you keep an `OsString` around and it's valid, converting it many times to `String` will be cheaper on Windows than Unix. However, if you receive many `OsString` values from the OS but never convert them to `String`, it will be cheaper on Unix than Windows due to Windows' up-front conversion.

So essentially, there's three options:

1. The OS gave you a valid string. The `OsString` is already valid UTF-8, and you can get those bytes with [`into_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsString.html#method.into_string) or [`to_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsString.html#method.to_str).
2. The OS gave you a possibly invalid string. You can check this with the previous methods, or you can call [`to_string_lossy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsString.html#method.to_string_lossy) to do automatic replacement.
3. If you want to actually know what the OS gave you, perhaps if you want to use a different replacement strategy or if you want to reinterpret the bytes, you can use [`encode_wide`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/ffi/trait.OsStrExt.html#tymethod.encode_wide) on Windows, or [`as_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/ffi/trait.OsStrExt.html#tymethod.as_bytes) or [`into_vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/ffi/trait.OsStringExt.html#tymethod.into_vec) on Unix.

Answer (score 1):

You could try converting the `OsString` into a plain `String` using the [`into_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsString.html#method.into_string) method. It may not succeed, but based on this comment in the documentation:

> In Rust, strings are always valid UTF-8, which may contain zeros.

It sounds like if it does succeed the resulting string will be valid UTF-8.

```rust
use std::ffi::OsString;

fn main() {
    let s = OsString::from("test");
    
    if let Ok(regular_string) = s.into_string() {
        println!("{regular_string}");
    } else {
        println!("???");
    }
}
```